# Bing Maps call infobox from outside table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

I have a map on the left and a table on the right. I would like hoverover the table cell and it to pop up the infobox on the map. I have the map mouseover working but don't know how to call it from outside the Map.

I am using MVC.

The table has 50 or so entries and the map has the corresponding pins I want to show the infobox for that pin when the table cell or text his mouse over.

Comment: You can use javascript - have `onmouseover` call a function that handles your popup

Comment: Yes but how. How do you find the correct pin and launch the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you already have or can manually create some unique id for each pushpin/table cell pair. Then after you create each pushpin, you can assign this info to its metadata:

```
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);
pushpin.metadata = { id: "Some Id" };
// ......
// Other work like binding infobox and mouseover event
```

Now Let's say you eventually add the pushpins to map like this:

```
var pushpins = [....];
var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer.add(pushpins);
map.layers.insert(layer);
```

And on the table side, bind the same id to a custom data attribute of the table cell:

```
<td data-pushpinId="Some Id">Cell A</td>
```

When you hover on the table cell, get its `data-pushpinId` and find the corresponding pushpin on the layer, then invoke its mouse over event.

```
var pushpinId = tableCell.getAttribute("data-pushpinId");
var pushpin = layer.getPrimitives().find((pushpin) => pushpin.metadata.id === pushpinId);
pushpin && pushpin.mouseover.invoke();
```